# When I change my application code do I have to remember to change the mocked functions in my tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

So I am unit testing my User class which makes call to my Database class. So at the moment I have this -

```
User.prototype.getUsername = function() {
    user = Database.loadUser(1);

    return user.username;
}

Database.prototype.loadUser = function(userId) {
    // Load user data from the database

    return {
        username: loadedUser.username,
        password: loadedUser.password,
        age: loadedUser.age
    };
}
```

So I mock the Database loadUser() function so that my User tests are isolated from the database layer. I make the mocked loadUser() function return an object that has the same properties as the real loadUser function -

```
MockDatabase.loadUser = function(userId) 
    return {
        username: 'mockUsername',
        password: 'mockPassword',
        age: 1
    };
}
```

So that's all fine. Now say a few days later I change the properties of the Database loadUser function so that it looks like this -

```
Database.prototype.loadUser = function(userId) {
    // Load user data from the database

    return {
        firstNanme: loadedUser.firstName,
        surname: loadedUser.surname
        password: loadedUser.password,
        age: loadedUser.age
    };
}
```

Well now my User class is still using the MockDatabase.loadUser() function as a mock during testing and the tests will pass even though when the actual program is run there will be an exception because the real Database.loadUser function no longer has a 'username' property.

So what's the solution to this issue? I imagine this is a very common situation. Do I just have to remember to also always keep mocked function in sync with real functions? That seems like a very inefficient and error-prone way of doing things..?

Comment: What language is this?  In a static-typed language, this is usually solved by defining an interface (and thus mismatches cause compilation errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your test loadUser function before you make the change to your real loadUser function.  Test Driven Development isn't just for when the code is first written, it's for any subsequent changes that you make too